# how to make the members in the class dynamic in java

Tags: java, oop

I have a class

```
public class MyClass {
    String str1;
    String str2;
    Myclass1 class1;
}
```

now, I want to have another class

```
public class MyClass {
    String str1;
    String str2;
    Myclass2 class2;
}
```

Notice how both classes have only one member different.
Is it possible in java that I just define one class for this and dynamically change the member when needed?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dynamically change"? You could have some common base-class for `Myclass1` and `Myclass2` - but that really depends on what you are intending to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a generic class. The name of the field would remain the same, though.

```java
class MyClass<T> {
    private String str1;
    private String str2;
    private T obj;
    public MyClass(String str1, String str2, T obj) {
        this.str1 = str1;
        this.str2 = str2;
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    // methods...
}
```

Example usage:

```java
MyClass<String> c1 = new MyClass<>("str1", "str2", "str3");
MyClass<Integer> c2 = new MyClass<>("str1", "str2", 1);
```